# is scheduled task still valid after redirect to another url in single page application

Tags: javascript

I am using Keycloak-js to manage token in my react SPA. When Keycloak gets the token, it will schedule a callback function: onTokenExpired by setTimeout. The onTokenExpired function is trigged ok if the code does not navigate to another path from the current component that I use to handle authentication. However I would like to navigate to other component if user is authenticated. If I navigate to another path, I do not see the onTokenExpired function be triggered any more.

Here is a simple code to demonstrate this issue:

on page http://localhost:3000/welcome

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  alert('callback function: refreshToken triggered')
},5000);
window.location='/helloWorld';
```

this alert window does not show up after I change the location.

I understand the cb function is firstly pushed onto the stack, then create a timer in webapi, when timer is over, the cb is sent to the callback queue and eventually picked up by the event loop and add into stack. But it is not clear to me if changing the url path would break this.

After all, is there a way to keep the scheduled task valid even after I navigate away from the current component?

Answer (score 0):

window.location loads the entire application hence I guess on the backend the timer is destroyed. To navigate to different component, use this.props.history.push('/helloWorld'). This resolves the issue.